# Docker ELKv6.6.1 Authentication

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I am not able to setup passwords for Kibana and ElastiCsearch. Please see below docker-compose.yml. I would appreciate if someone could put me in right direction?

> Use Case: I would like to setup authentication/login for Kibana and Elastic
>   Search.
>   Note: fyi, I posted same query on [elastic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/advice-on-docker-elkv6-6-1-authentication/171665) blog.

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "ELASTIC_PASSWORD=MagicWord"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.1
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200/
      elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
      elasticsearch.password: "kibanapassword"
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
volumes:
  esdata:
```